# Msg 207 Invalid column name $node_id for pseudo column in inline table valued function

Tags: graph-databases, sql-server-2017, sql-server-2017-graph

In a Node-table the pseudo column name `$node_id` refers to the internal name of the node id column and using the pseudo column is recommended (see [SQL Graph Architecture §Node Table](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/graphs/sql-graph-architecture#node-table)).

For example after creating the following table:

```
create table [Sites](
[SiteName] NVarChar(max) NOT NULL,
[EndPoint] NVarChar(max),
[SiteNameHash] as CheckSum([SiteName]) PERSISTED NOT NULL,
[EndPointHash] as CheckSum([EndPoint]) PERSISTED NOT NULL,

INDEX IX_Sites_NodeId UNIQUE CLUSTERED ($node_id),
INDEX IX_Sites_SiteName UNIQUE NONCLUSTERED (SiteNameHash, $node_id),
INDEX IX_Sites_EndPoint UNIQUE NONCLUSTERED (EndPointHash, $node_id))

as Node;
```

The query:

```
SELECT $node_id
  ,[SiteName]
  ,[EndPoint]
  ,[SiteNameHash]
  ,[EndPointHash]
FROM [EmersonAnalysis].[dbo].[Sites]
where $node_id =  '{"type":"node","schema":"dbo","table":"Sites","id":0}'
```

uses the pseudo column `$node_id` in the `SELECT`-clause and in the `WHERE`-clause to select a single node (if it exists).

However, on the following table valued function:

```
create function SitesByName(
    @sitename as NVarChar(max))
RETURNS TABLE
WITH SCHEMABINDING
AS
    return select
        $node_id,
        [SiteName],
        [EndPoint],
        [SiteNameHash],
        [EndPointHash]
    from [dbo].[Sites]
    where [SiteNameHash] = CHECKSUM(@sitename) AND
        [SiteName] = @sitename;
```

The similar query:

```
select
    fn.$node_id
from [Sites]
outer apply SitesByName([SiteName]) as fn
```

Results in the error message:

> Msg 207, Level 16, State 1, Line 2
>   Invalid column name '$node_id'.

Is it possible to use pseudo column names when selecting columns from functions? If so, how can I use pseudo column names?

PS. I'm using [sql-server-2017](/questions/tagged/sql-server-2017) RC 2 v14.0.900.75.

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/q/195530/814206 for information about pseudo columns.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Workarround: you can define an alias for `$node_id` in the table valued function and use that in your select instead of the pseudo column:

```
ALTER function [dbo].[SitesByName](
    @sitename as NVarChar(max))
RETURNS TABLE
WITH SCHEMABINDING
AS
    return select
        $node_id [NodeId],
        [SiteName],
        [EndPoint],
        [SiteNameHash],
        [EndPointHash]
    from [dbo].[Sites]
    where [SiteNameHash] = CHECKSUM(@sitename) AND
        [SiteName] = @sitename;
```

If fact `SSMS` displays a red squiggly line (likely an error or warning) under `[SitesByName]` with the text:

> No column was specified for column '1' of 'SitesByName'