# Use views and table valued functions as node or edge tables in match clauses

Tags: graph, graph-databases, sql-server-2017, sql-graph, sql-server-2017-graph

I like to use [Table Valued functions](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/statements/create-function-transact-sql) in [`MATCH`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/queries/match-sql-graph) clauses in the same way as is possible with [`Node` tables](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/statements/create-table-sql-graph).  Is there a way to achieve this?

### The need for table valued functions

There can be various use cases for using table valued functions or views as [`Node` tables](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/statements/create-table-sql-graph).  For instance mine is the following.
I have `Node` tables that contain `NVarChar(max)` fields that I would like to search for literal text.  I need only equality searching and no [full text searching](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/search/get-started-with-full-text-search), so I opted for using a index on the [hash value](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/checksum-transact-sql) of the text field.  As suggested by [Remus Rusanu](https://stackoverflow.com/users/105929/remus-rusanu) in his [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8002357/814206) to [SQL server - worth indexing large string keys?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/8001905/814206) and https://www.brentozar.com/archive/2013/05/indexing-wide-keys-in-sql-server/.  A table valued function handles using the [`CHECKSUM`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/checksum-transact-sql) index; see [Msg 207 Invalid column name $node_id for pseudo column in inline table valued function](https://stackoverflow.com/q/45565111/814206).

### Example data definitions

```
CREATE TABLE [Tags](
    [tag] NVarChar(max),
    [tagHash] AS CHECKSUM([Tag]) PERSISTED NOT NULL
) as Node;

CREATE TABLE [Sites](
    [endPoint] NVarChar(max),
    [endPointHash] AS CHECKSUM([endPoint]) PERSISTED NOT NULL
) as Node;

CREATE TABLE [Links] as Edge;

CREATE INDEX [IX_TagsByName] ON [Tags]([tagHash]);

GO

CREATE FUNCTION [TagsByName](
    @tag NVarChar(max))
RETURNS TABLE
WITH SCHEMABINDING
AS
RETURN SELECT
    $node_id AS [NodeId],
    [tag],
    [tagHash]
FROM [dbo].[Tags]
WHERE [tagHash] = CHECKSUM(@tag) AND
    [tag] = @tag;
```

`[TagsByName]` returns the [`$node_id`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/graphs/sql-graph-architecture#node-table) with an alias `NodeId` as suggested by https://stackoverflow.com/a/45565410/814206.  However, real [`Node` tables](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/statements/create-table-sql-graph) contain two more internal columns which I do not know how to export.

### Desired query

I would like to query the database similar to this:

```
SELECT *
FROM [TagsByName]('important') as t,
    [Sites] as s,
    [Links] as l
WHERE MATCH ([t]-([l])->[s])
```

However, this results in the error<sup>1</sup>:

> Msg 13901, Level 16, State 2, Line ...
>   Identifier 't' in a [`MATCH`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/queries/match-sql-graph) clause is not a [node table](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/statements/create-table-sql-graph) or an alias for a node table.

I there a way to do this?

---

PS. There are some workarounds but they do not look as elegant as the `MATCH`-query; especially considering that my actual query involves matching more relations and more string equality tests.  I will post these workarounds as answers and hope that someone comes with a better idea.

<sup>1</sup> <sub>This gives a very specific difference between views and tables for [Difference between View and table in sql](https://stackoverflow.com/q/6015175/814206); which only occurs in [sql-server-2017](/questions/tagged/sql-server-2017) and only when using SQL Graph.</sub>

Answer (score 0, accepted):

### Workaround

Add the `Node` table twice to the from clause: once as table and once as table valued function and join them via the `$node_id` in the where clause:

```
SELECT *
FROM [TagsByName]('important') as t1,
    [Tags] as t2,
    [Sites] as s,
    [Links] as l
WHERE MATCH ([t2]-([l])->[s]) AND
    t1.[NodeId] = t2.$node_id
```

*Does this affect performance?*

Answer (score 0):

### Workaround

Revert to traditional relational joins via [`JOIN`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/queries/from-transact-sql) clauses or [`FROM` with `<table_or_view_name>`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/queries/from-transact-sql) and `WHERE` clauses.  In queries that [match](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/queries/match-sql-graph) on more relations, the latter has the advantage that [sql-server-2017-graph](/questions/tagged/sql-server-2017-graph) can [`MATCH`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/queries/match-sql-graph) on [`FROM <table_or_view_name>`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/queries/from-transact-sql) but not on [`FROM <table_source> JOIN <table_source>`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/queries/from-transact-sql).

```
SELECT *
FROM [TagsByName]('important') as t
    [Sites] as s,
    [Links] as l
WHERE t.NodeId = l.$from_id AND
    l.$to_id = s.$node_id;
```

Answer (score 0):

### Workaround

Do not use the table valued function, but include its expression in the `WHERE` clause:

```
SELECT *
FROM [Tags] as t,
    [Sites] as s,
    [Links] as l
WHERE MATCH ([t]-([l])->[s]) AND
    [t].[tagHash] = CHECKSUM('important') AND
    [t].[tag] = 'important'
```

*Downside: This is easy to get wrong; for example by forgetting to join on the `CHECKSUM`*